# how to reduce padding when embedding highcharts?

Tags: highcharts, padding

I'm having trouble embedding a highcharts pie chart in an html document. Specifically, I can't resize the chart's container without changing the size of the chart. Does anyone know if you can reduce the default padding without shrinking the chart? Alternatively, can you increase the diameter of the chart without increasing the width of the container?

Answer (score 3):

You can reduce padding / spacing / margins http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart or increase size http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.pie.size

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't found the size option, but that did it.

Comment: i was trying to do point padding in pie charts https://jsfiddle.net/Kondaldurgam/po5Lf0sk/4/ but its not working can u please check once -sebastian Bochan